# .NET5 WebApi project infinite loading on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, api, iis

I recently created an API that will be hosted on a local machine to our intranet. It is built as a .net core webapi project targeting .NET5

I deployed it to IIS using an App pool with the No managed code setting. And I added Authenticated Users as well as IIS_IUSRS to security.

Now when I try post to the api it just keeps loading, and in browser if I open a request it also just loads to no end.

Thanks

Comment: First, identity where the requests go by enabling IIS Failed Request Tracing, as well as ASP.NET Core module logging, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis

Comment: In addition to enabling logging, you can also make sure that IIS_IUSRS has read and write permissions. Failure to read web.config can also cause continuous loading. Ensure that the correct host bundle is installed.

Comment: Same issue.
Have you found the solution?